# LP modeling issue (factory process)

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, operations-research

I am working on a linear programming problem in the following logistic network : $F_1$ and $F_2$ are supply nodes, $U_1$ and $U_2$ are factories, $C_1$ and $C_2$ are customers.

- $A$ and $B$ are produced at nodes $F_1$, $F_2$
- $P$ and $Q$ are produced at nodes $U_1$, $U_2$ with the following requirements: $1$ unit of $P$ requires $1$ unit of $A$ and $0.5$ units of $B$; $1$ unit of $Q$ requires $0.2$ units of $A$ and $0.3$ units of $B$.

I have a doubt on how to model this. If $p_{i}^u$ denotes the amount of product $i \in \{P,Q\}$ that is produced by factory $u \in \{U_1,U_2\}$ and $c_{i}^u$ the amount of product $i\in \{A,B\}$ that is consumed (for the production of $P$ and $Q$) by factory $u\in \{U_1,U_2\}$, it is tempting to write
$$
p_P^{U_1} = c_A^{U_1}+0.5\;c_B^{U_1}\\
p_Q^{U_1} = 0.2\;c_A^{U_1}+0.3\;c_B^{U_1}\\
$$
However, this is wrong as the solver could for example set $p_P^{U_1}$ to $1$ with $c_A^{U_1}=1$ and $c_B^{U_B}=0$, which is incorrect.

Someone told me to write the equations the other way around as follows:
$$
c_A^{U_1} = p_P^{U_1}+0.2\;p_Q^{U_1}\\
c_B^{U_1} = 0.5\;p_P^{U_1}+0.3\;p_Q^{U_1}\\
$$

Is this correct ? If not, what is the appropriate way to write these equations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all let me come back to your first attempt as I think that it is important to understand **why** it does not work. Then I will try to give you some pointers as to why the second set of equations is **probably** correct.

---

Your first attempt at modeling the problem was as follows:
\begin{align}
p_P^{U_1} = c_A^{U_1} + 0.5~c_B^{U_1} \\
p_Q^{U_1} = 0.2~c_A^{U_1} + 0.3~c_B^{U_1} \text{.}
\end{align}
It does not work because:

- The meaning of each equation is not **consistent** with the problem considered. Put into words the equations correspond to the following sentences:

  > $1$ unit of $P$ requires $1$ unit of $A$ **or** $0.5$ units of $B$; $1$ unit of $Q$ requires $0.2$ units of $A$ **or** $0.3$ units of $B$
- These equations do not take into account that the raw material is most certainly **consumed** when creating a product. In other words, if there is a **limited** amount of raw materials these two equations do not take into account the **trade-off** that exists between the quantity $p_P^{U_1}$ of product $P$ produced and the quantity $p_Q^{U_1}$ of product $Q$. Similarly if the goal is to produce a **certain amount** of each product then these equations do not take into account the fact that the raw materials $A$ and $B$ used to create product $P$ are **disjoint** from the raw materials $A$ and $B$ used to create product $Q$.

---

Your second attempt at modeling the problem is as follows:
\begin{align}
c_A^{U_1} = p_P^{U_1} + 0.2~p_Q^{U_1} \\
c_B^{U_1} = 0.5~p_P^{U_1} + 0.3~p_Q^{U_1} \text{.}
\end{align}

This is **probably** correct:

- The meaning of each equation is respectively:

  > $1$ unit of $A$ can be used to produce $1$ unit of $P$ **or** $5$ units of $Q$; $1$ unit of $B$ can be used to produce $2$ units of $P$ **or** $\frac{1}{0.3}$ units of $Q$
- If you produce one unit of product $P$ you will increase the need in both $A$ **and** $B$ since $p_P^{U_1}$ appears in both equations. In other words if you need to produce a **certain amount** of each product the amount of raw materials needed will be correct.
- If there is a **limited** amount of raw materials (fixed $c_A^{U_1}$ and $c_B^{U_1}$) these two equations take into account the **trade-off** that exists between the quantity $p_P^{U_1}$ of product $P$ produced and the quantity $p_Q^{U_1}$ of product $Q$. In other words if you consume some raw materials to produce the product $P$ then you have less raw materials available for product $Q$.

Here I said that it is probably correct because you did not give the **underlying problem** that you want to solve (Maximizing the number of products created under a limited amount of raw materials, Maximizing your profit when selling your products, Minimizing the amount of raw material used for a given profit,...). If I cannot think of a counter example right away it might still happen that you need to change your model to solve a specific problem (in fact it is very likely that you will need to add more equations).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanations. There is one point that remains unlcear to me: Since $1$ unit of $P$ requires  $0.5$ units of $B$ and $1$ unit of $Q$ requires $0.3$ units of $Q$, shouldn't it be 
$$
c_B = \frac{1}{0.5}p_P +  \frac{1}{0.3}p_Q \quad ?
$$

Comment: The fact that $1$ unit of $P$ requires $0.5$ units of B does not mean that $p_P = 0.5~c_B$ but rather that $0.5~p_P = c_B$. To see that try to consider having only $1$ unit of $B$ and ask yourself how many $P$ you can create with that.

Comment: Yes of course...Thanks again!